# How to pass SOAP request to Camel CXF

Tags: apache-camel

I have a requirement "While routing in camel, i have to call a web service". But i am struck with setting SOAP xml to the exchange. Can some one help me with this. Please have a look at my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("file:input?noop=true")
                        .process(new Processor() {
                            @Override
                            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                                //Setting a String to the exchange body
                                exchange.getIn().setBody("Just a String");
                                //Now i want to set a SOAP xml to the exchange body
                                //exchange.getIn().setBody();
                                System.out.println("Ravi "+ exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
                            }
                        })
                        .to("cxf://http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?wsdlURL=src/main/resources/META-INF/stockquote.wsdl&serviceName={http://www.webserviceX.NET/}StockQuote&portName={http://www.webserviceX.NET/}StockQuoteSoap&dataFormat=MESSAGE")
                        .process(new Processor() {
                            @Override
                            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                                System.out.println("Raju" + exchange);
                            }
                        }).to("file:data/destination?fileName=test2.xml");
            }
        });
        context.start();
        Thread.sleep(20000);
        context.stop();
    }
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear. Do you intend to use the payload of file:input as the xml in the request? Do you want to set the entire SOAP envelope or just the Body part? If Body, have you tried the PAYLOAD data format?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm understanding correctly, but give you an example (in spring dsl) in case it helps.

1. Setup the endpoint with PAYLOAD mode:

   ```
   <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="myEndpoint" ... >
       <cxf:properties>
           <entry key="dataFormat" value="PAYLOAD"/>
       </cxf:properties>
   </cxf:cxfEndpoint>
   ```
2. Then in your route:

   ```
   <from uri="direct:webservicecall"/>
   <to uri="language:constant:classpath:FileContainingBody.xml"/>
   <to uri="cxf:bean:myEndpoint?defaultOperationName=MyMethod"/>
   ```

The main point here is using the "language" component to load the body for the request, having previously configured your endpoint in PAYLOAD mode, as Petter suggested.